# Bayes rule denominator is confusing

Tags: bayes

I'm trying to make sense of a fishing problem using Bayes rule.

$$
P(K>0\mid y=1) = \frac{P( y=1|K>0 )P(k>0)}{P( y=1|K>0 )P(K>0)\; +\; P( y=1|K=0 )P(K=0)}
$$

I'm framing a problem where K is the number of fish caught and y is 1 if I went fishing and 0 if I didn't go fishing.

I find the denominator part to be confusing. While I get the first part, I am not sure how to make sense of the "$P(y=1|K=0 )P(K=0)$" part. Can I interpret this as the probability of going fishing but not catching anything, i.e., prob(going fishing but not catching anything) * prob(not catching anything)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the denominator re-wrapped:

$$\begin{align*} 
    & P(y=1 \mid k>0) P(k>0) + P(y=1 \mid k=0) P(k=0) \\
    \!&= P(y=1 \ \text{and} \ k >0) + P(y=1 \ \text{and} \ k=0) \\
    \!&= P(y=1) 
\end{align*}$$

So:

- First term: Going fishing *and* catching at least one thing.
- Second term: Going fishing *and* not catching anything.

The word *but* is a synonym for *and* in this kind of sentence: "... and a negative event ...".

> My data includes only days when I went fishing, so shouldn't P(y=1) equal 1?

If you're applying this example of Bayes rule in the situation you describe then, yes, I suppose.  In that case your entire equation reduces to the tautology:

$$ P(k > 0) = P(k > 0) $$

so Bayes isn't telling you anything at all.  This isn't surprising, you're conditioning on a certain event, which adds no information.

Comment: My data includes only days when I went fishing, so shouldn't P(y=1) equal 1?

Comment: @user3007270 Responded in the answer.